# python - writing into html file converts the special characters

Tags: python, html, elementtree

I am trying to write into a html file using python, any tags that I add are getting coverted

e.g. `<tr>` to `&lt;tr&gt;`

Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid it?

In the html page, the exact text that I inserted appears rather than being treated as html tags

Part of the Code:

```
htmlReport=ElementTree()
htmlReport.parse('result_templte.html')
strTable="<tr><td>Text here</td></tr>"

for node in htmlReport.findall('.//*[@id="table1"]')
    node.text=strTable

htmlReport.write("results.html")
```

this writes the html tag as `&lt;` `&gt;` into the file. so the tags inserted are not treated as proper html tags

Comment: Plain Python code without any other libraries, writing the string `'<tr>'` to a file won't escape HTML, so you are not using just plain Python. Please show us a [mcve] so we can actually say something meaningful as to why your text is being escaped.

Comment: updated the text, hope that helps

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a real templating engine, like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add an element as a child of another element, but you are actually just adding a plain text string that happens to contain `<` and `>` markup delimiters. To make it work, you need to parse the string to get a new element object and add (append) it in the right place.

Let's assume that template.html looks like this:

```
<html>

 <table>
 </table>

 <table id="table1">
 </table>

</html>
```

Then you can add a `tr` element as a child of the second `table` as follows:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('template.html')

# Get the wanted 'table' element
table = tree.find(".//table[@id='table1']")

# Parse string to create a new element
tr = ET.fromstring("<tr><td>Text here</td></tr>")

# Append 'tr' as a child of 'table'
table.append(tr)

tree.write("results.html")
```

This is what results.html looks like:

```
<html>

 <table>
 </table>

 <table id="table1">
 <tr><td>Text here</td></tr></table>

</html>
```